# Flask: Unicode error when trying to parse POST payload

Tags: python, flask, unicode

I'm trying to build a Flask API endpoint that takes an image url from the JSON payload. I'm using `flask.request.get_json()` which has worked for me before:

```
@app.route("/caption", methods=["POST"])
def caption():
    image_url = flask.request.get_json().get('image_url')
    image_info = get_caption(image_url)
    return flask.jsonify(image_info)
```

However, when trying to post a URL to the endpoint with content type `application/json` I get an `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'image_url'`

I tried printing out the contents of `flask.request.get_json()` and I get

```
{u'image_url': u'https://images.pexels.com/photos/66997/pexels-photo-66997.jpeg'}
```

How can I get my payload as a dictionary instead of a unicode object?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're testing it wrong if `flask.request.get_json()` returns the dictionary you've posted.

Comment: @zwer I tried both curl and Postman, and I'm using application/json content type.

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't think flask.request.get_json() return you the dictionary you posted as @zwer mentioned.
But if you really get that dictionary.
Try to do this to achieve your aim.

```
import json
def caption():
    image_json = flask.request.get_json()
    image_url = json.loads(json.dumps(image_json)).get('image_url')
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using python2 and you can print out the result so why not print out the type of the the dictionary-like object and find out its type.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that the error was in the way I handled `image_url` in my `get_caption` function. The error message led me to believe that the problem was with parsing the payload. I apologize for the misunderstanding. Thanks everyone who answered, you helped me find the bug.

Comment: I was having a similar problem--glad a dictionary can still work even if it displays 'u when printed.